How to fix the ms-high-contrast deprecation problem in Microsoft Edge console?
I'm getting this error in my Microsoft Edge console:
dynamicCSS.js:74
[Deprecation]-ms-high-constrast is in the process of being deprecated. Please see https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2024/04/29/deprecating-ms-high-contrast/ for tips on updating to the new Forced Colors Mode standard.
When I look at dynamicCSS.js:74, I don't see anything that could cause this issue:
container.insertBefore(styleNode, existStyle[existStyle.length - 1].nextSibling);
My website page works, but I was told to solve this issue at my job
I've tried updating my rc-util library using this:
yarn upgrade rc-util
It didn't help, and the file "node_modules/rc-util/es/Dom/dynamicCSS.js" hasn't changed
I've also tried searching for usages of ms-high-contrast in my project, but I haven't found anything.

I was able to get rid of the warning by just overriding it in my globals css file (even though I also had zero instances of this in my code anywhere).
* {
  -ms-high-contrast: none !important;
}

